# How to show stickers (or other views) under UIInputAccessoryView on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, chat

I'm building a chat interface and I'm curious how apps like Telegram and iMessage achieve the following:

1. There's an always-on input bar that stays above the keyboard (or at the bottom of the screen if there's no keyboard). This is most likely a `UIInputAccessoryView`, and I've got this implemented.
2. There's a sticker button on the bar that, when tapped, dismisses the keyboard AND keeps the input bar in-place AND reveals another view under it that is some other view (containing stickers, etc.) The input bar basically doesn't move at all. The animation is exactly like the keyboard going away, revealing the view that appears to have always been there.
3. If the keyboard is hidden, tapping on the sticker button does the same as 2. What's really cool is that the sticker view is always the same height as the keyboard - and note that keyboards of different languages can be of different height (autocomplete bar), and at least in Telegram's case it can always find the right height.

Any pointer to how to achieve this is appreciated!

[image: text message]
[image: sticker]